# robobrowser 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, robobrowser

```
import re
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

email = 'example@gmail.com'
senha = '12342343'
br = RoboBrowser()
br.open("https://www.ifood.com.br/entrar/")
form = br.get_form()
form['email_login'] = email
form['password_login'] = senha
br.submit_form(form)
```

I need help with logging in, but it always raises exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LUCAS\Desktop\ifood.py", line 11, in <module>
    form['email_login'] = email
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: `br.get_form()` goes not return what you think it does...

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Try using selenium instead, maybe?

Comment: Check the value of `form `before doing anything with/to it. `form` is probably ` None`.

Comment: `get_form(id=None, *args, **kwargs)`;  Find form by ID, as well as standard BeautifulSoup arguments.  Parameters: `id (str)` – Form ID; Returns: BeautifulSoup tag if found, else `None`